# How to call a function using href in angular 2/ type script

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to call a function in type script component from `<a>` tag using `href` like this:

```
  <a href="fun()" ></a>
```

Is it possible in some way? Note that I need only this way. Using a `click` event does not help in my case.

I tried already this:

```
<a href="javascript:fun()">
```

But it does not work.

thanks!

Comment: No you  need a click event else use vanila javascript

Answer (score 27):

you cannot call function in href use `role` attribute and make `<a>` as button and call the function with `(click)`

```
<a role="button" (click)="func()"></a>
```

Comment: When I use this syntax, my link styles arent applied.  e.g.:  a:active, a:hover, a:focus  I tried adding an href="#". The link styles are applied, but clicking link takes me to root/# which obviously isn't what I want. Is there a way to have your solution work with the applied styles?

Comment: @Franciscod'Anconia Yes, you can set `href` to `javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question. This worked for me on Angular 6 -

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="getSampleCSV()">CSV Template</a>
```

Comment: Works fine and causes no problems with styles, contrary to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999892/6422750.

Answer (score 7):

Something I noticed when addressing a similar issue is that you can surround your function call with {{ }} to have angular actually call the function.

```
<a href={{"javascript:fun()}}"> </a>
```

In my particular problem, I was trying to generate a dynamic link based on other information so I did something like

html:

```
<a href="{{generateCustomLink(data)}}" target="_blank"></a>
```

typescript:

```
generateCustomLink(data: any) : string {
    return 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For new visitors, you can also call like below:

> in mycomponent.component.html

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="onLogoutClick()">Logout</a>
```

> And, and in mycomponent.component.ts

```
  onLogoutClick() {
    console.log("Logout Clicked");
    //define your logic
  }
```