# How to call a function using href without turing it into a button so it can be right click opened in a new tab in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, href

I have a div which contains a function, when clicking on the div it openes a new page defined in the function.
Now I want to be able to right click on the div so the page can be opened in a new tab.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999648/how-to-call-a-function-using-href-in-angular-2-type-script) question and other similar ones and there are always two solutions, either turn the  into a btn and call the function this way.
But this way the right click does not work anymore.

The other one is calling the function in the href, but for some reason this does not work for me:

```
<!-- This one does not call the function on left click but is right click able and can open a new tab, but an empty one-->
<a href="javascript:onEventNameClick(isDm, danceEvent);" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">

<!-- This one calls the function but is not right clickable, does not have the option to open in a new tab -->
<a class ="btn" (click)="onEventNameClick(isDm, danceEvent)" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
```

So how can I call the function to get the correct page and have the ability to open it in a new tab using href

Edit:
Using this code calls the function on left click as intended but when opening the link in a new tab with right click, returns the"about:blank#blocked" page

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="onEventNameClick(isDm, danceEvent)" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
```

the function which gets called:

```
  onEventNameClick(isDm: boolean, danceEvent?: DanceEvent): void {
    if (isDm) {
      if (danceEvent) {
        this._router.navigate(['preview', danceEvent.id], {
          relativeTo: this._route,
          // queryParams: { danceEventId: danceEvent.id },
        });
      } else {
        this._router.navigate(['preview'], { relativeTo: this._route });
      }
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/dance-event', this.danceEvent.id]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide where the `onEventNameClick` function is placed or the whole code of this component. Depending on the data we have to process it in different ways

Comment: @TachibanaShin I have added the function, it gets called in the .ts file, the function does work as intented when I left click the div element which is wrapped in the <a>, but on right click it does just return the blank page

Answer (score 0):

my answer assumes that the `onEventNameClick` function is in component:

```js
<a href="<your href>" (click)="onEventNameClick($event, isDm, danceEvent)" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
```

and `onEventNameClick`:

```js
  onEventNameClick($event: MouseEvent, isDm: boolean, danceEvent?: DanceEvent): void {
    $event.preventDefault();

    if (isDm) {
      if (danceEvent) {
        this._router.navigate(['preview', danceEvent.id], {
          relativeTo: this._route,
          // queryParams: { danceEventId: danceEvent.id },
        });
      } else {
        this._router.navigate(['preview'], { relativeTo: this._route });
      }
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/dance-event', this.danceEvent.id]);
    }
  }
```

if you call function when click mouse right in `<a>` you have add event `contextmenu`

```js
<a href="<your href>" (click)="onEventNameClick($event, isDm, danceEvent)" (contextmenu)="onEventNameClick($event, isDm, danceEvent)" style="text-decoration: none; color:inherit;">
```

Comment: i applyed your changed but it still acts the same, when left clicking on the content it adds the correct page, when right clicking the content and opening it in a new tab it opens about:blank#blocked, an empty page

when adding the contextmenu i can not right click the content anymore, on right click it  it opens the same tab again in a new one

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. your question only goes to that extent can you take a video and then describe it?